# Create Star Pattern

Tags: for-loop

I'm trying to make stars with pattern:

```
*
*
**
*
**
***
```

But with this code i can only draw this:

```
*
*
*
**
*
***
```

Anyone can help me? this is the code. Thank you

```
   int main(){
            int angka;
        while (true){
                printf("masukkan angka : ");
                scanf("%d", &angka);
                fflush(stdin);

                for(int i=1; i<=angka; i++){
                    printf("\n*\n");
                    for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    printf("\n");   
            }
            getchar();
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
//Print 1st star
printf("*");
printf("\n");

//Print 2nd and 3rd row stars

for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)       
{
    printf("*");
}
printf("\n");
}

//Print last pyramid row stars

for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
{
for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)       
{
    printf("*");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

OutPut:-

```
*                                                                                                                                          
*                                                                                                                                          
**                                                                                                                                         
*                                                                                                                                          
**                                                                                                                                         
***
```

I tried with above code and I get same output which you want.
In above code first star and for 2nd and 3rd rows I use 2 for loop and for 4th and 5th I use for loop.